# How to access controls in dynamicly added UserControl?

Tags: c#, user-controls

I have a UserControl with form elements where I dynamicly load a subform:

```
subForm = Page.LoadControl("/subforms/ReservationType_" + value + ".ascx")
DynamicFormPart.Controls.Add(subForm);
```

How can I access the values of the form elements on the dynamicly loaded subform?

These things didn't work:

```
var gameCheckBox = _subForm.FindControl("GameCheckBox") as CheckBox;

var gameCategory = DynamicFormPart.FindControl("GameCategory") as DropDownList;

var checkBoxMtbDistance = this.Page.FindControl("CheckBoxMtbDistance") as CheckBox;
```

So how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: controls on a form(added through toolbox drag-drop or explicitly declaring them as private) are private,and its not the best choice to modify to protected or public(unless in very especific situations),you can "expose" just the fuctionality you need through public methods for example in your subform.There is a "backdoor",the    _subForm.Controls is accessible but my first remark will be better...

Comment: Btw instead of adding a .ascx file i now render the controls with the code behind. This is the solution: Re-render the dynamic fields when a post is done: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           if (IsPostBack) _RenderOptionalFields(ReservationFor.SelectedValue);